# can't render fetched api data on my nextjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

on this nextjs project i'm fetching data from an api and it's logging successfully. but i just can't seem to render the response (from the handleSubmit const) on my main jsx return. i try it as

{cart.categoryTitle}

and i got no error, but also no render on my app. am i doing something wrong? thanks!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Lista = () => {
  const [categoryTitle, setCategoryTitle] = useState<any>();
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([])

  interface Data {
    id: number;
    title: string;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleCategoryData();
  }, []);

  async function handleCategoryData() {
    const response = await fetch("/api/category");
    const categoryTitle = await response.json();
    setCategoryTitle(categoryTitle);
  }


  const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const categoryTitle = event.target[0].value;
    const sub = event.target[1].value;
    const name = [event.target[2].value];
    const type = event.target[3].value == "Unidade" ? "unit" : "kg";
    const price = event.target[4].value;
    const counter = event.target[5].value;
    //const img = event.target[6].value;
    const res = await fetch("../api/list", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        products: [
          {
            categoryTitle,
            sub,
            name,
            type,
            price,
            quantity,
          },
        ],
      }),
    });
    const response = await res.json();
    console.log(response);
    // return JSON.stringify(response);
    setCart(response)
  };

  if (!categoryTitle) return <p>Loading</p>;
  if (!sub) return <p>Loading</p>;
  if (!productResponse) return <p>Loading</p>;

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <div className="listsContainer">
          <div className="cartContainer">
            <div className="listText">
              <p>Lista</p>
              <p>{cart.categoryTitle}</p>
              <p>0 categorias / 0 itens</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the response look like? Is it an object that has `categoryTitle` property? It may be the case that there’s no `categoryTitle` in the response object. Your cart state is being initialize as an array so maybe you are expecting the response to be an array as well?

Comment: Maybe you should access it as `cart[0].categoryTitle` or map through the cart state and render the categoryTitle

Comment: hi Wani, there is a categoryTitle property. i tried to erase this cart state and just console log the output outside of the handleSubmit function and the result is always ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: Can you please post the response here? With regards to the ReferenceError, you are logging `response` outside of its scope. It is being declared inside the handleSubmit function so you can't reference it outside.